# Android scaling text and images based on screen size (phone vs tablet)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a good understanding of the difference between px, dp and sp.
The problem is, when I put a TextView ( or ImageView ) on the screen, the dpi is irrelevant.
On a 3 inch high screen with 160 dpi, a text size of 80px will be 1/2 an inch, or 1/6th the height. On a 7 inch high screen with 160 dpi, it's still 1/2 inch, but that is now 1/14th of the height.

The problem is, using dp (or sp), what looks good on a phone disappears on a tablet.

Is there a way to specify fractional screen size, like percent?

Comment: There is not way to consistently do this. I suggest a redesign and use a image + text into an image kinda workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not sure if you can specify size in percent, but why you dont define different dimensions for screen in dimen.xml file. It is very hard to use the same values dp and sp for all screen sizes.

You need to create different dimens.xml different resource folders

```
 res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml
 res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml
 res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
```

Next add some values to these files

```
 <!-- in values-ldpi/dimens.xml -->
 <dimen name="textSize">25dip</dimen>

 <!-- in values-mdpi/dimens.xml -->
 <dimen name="textSize">20dip</dimen>
```

Finaly reference to dimensions in your layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/at"
    android:layout_below="@id/hw"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you want set height of image to 1/10 of screen size you need to use android:layout_weight attribute in your view containers. Check the example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            >
 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the problem is that dp, sp and px are irrelevant. If I want an image to be 1/10th of the screen height, how do I specify that?

Comment: Yes, thank you Kamil. I played with layout_weight and now my images are scaling correctly. I'll keep searching for a text size solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will give textSize depending upon the density.

```
  TextView text = new TextView(this);
  text.setText("text");
  TextView.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

**OR**

Create dimens.xml in values-ldpi,mdpi and hdpi.

```
<dimen name="textSize">30dip</dimen>
<dimen name="textSize">10dip</dimen>
```

and then add this in your layout.

```
<TextView
android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
    //rest code here
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response 23imak. It looks like I'll need to do a java code solution like the one you posted, maybe in a custom view. I was hoping android had a "fit text to rectangle" type of attribute in the layout xml, but they don't.